# load jQuery UI .datepicker for a WP frontend plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, wordpress, jquery-ui-datepicker

First, I feel like I've read the whole stack of posts in this category about a 100 times. While the title sounds like a duplicate, I really mean I've tried all solutions I read to the questions asked around up to the whole concatenate thing with WP 3.5+.

My script works great in WP when I reference the actual jquery script & url. I'm reading everywhere this is a terrible way to implement so I've been trying to use the built-in WP libraries and no-conflict wrapper. I run WP 3.6 on a barebone local InstandWP install with default twentythirteen theme and no other plugin.

```
\\ Works great if I use these in WP 3.6
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

As I said earlier, I'm trying to do the right thing, so I've made experiments with a number of enqueue and/or (de)register options. So far none succeeded:

- Concatenate_scripts = false
- (de)register jQuery
- Enqueue (with the proper jQuery hooks as referenced in the Codex)

Of course I re-write the $ into jQuery and so on; but my issue seem to be up-hill, as the firebug console tells me :
    Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

So here I am. My code is good outside of WP, but I can't seem to get it to use it for a front-end plugin in WP with good coding practices.

```
\\ Loading the JS library & CSS
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.1/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.min.css" />

\\ Definition of the datepicker rule
<script>
$(".full_date").datepicker({
showOn: 'button',
buttonText: 'Here',
dateFormat: 'DD, dd MM yy',
altFormat: "yy-mm",
altField: ".year-month",
onClose: function (dateText, picker) {
    // getDate returns a js Date object
     var dateObject = $(this).datepicker("getDate");
    console.dir(dateObject);
    // Call Date object methods
    $("#date input").val(dateObject.getDate());
    $("#month input").val(dateObject.getMonth());
    $("#day input").val(dateObject.getDay());
    $("#year input").val(dateObject.getFullYear());
}
});
</script>

\\ Some HTML
<h1>Date Picker</h1>

<form class="date-picker">
<label>full date</label>
<input type="text" class="full_date" value="" />
    <label>year month</label>
<input type="text" class="year-month"/>
</form>
<p id="day">Day of the week: <input name="day" type="text"></input> </p>
<p id="month">Month: <input name="month" type="text"></input></p>
<p id="date">Date: <input name="date" type="text"></input></p>
<p id="year">Year: <input name="year" type="text"></input></p>
```

If that helps, I have the whole thing on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/toutgreg/4kzEJ/)

Pretty please, could you just help on the syntax to get the code set the right way in WP 3.6+ ?

Thank you very much for taking the time to read through this.
Greg

**UPDATE**

Here's the updated code. I still have an error :
    "Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined".

```
<?php
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_my_scripts');

function load_my_scripts(){
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-datepicker', '/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/jquery.ui.datepicker.min.js', array('jquery'));    
wp_register_style('date-picker', plugins_url('includes/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.css',__FILE__), true);
}
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function($){
        $("#datepicker").datepicker();
    });
});
</script>
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" /></p>
```

You can see it live here:

> > http://s146485761.onlinehome.fr/wp_dev/debugging-test/

The full plugin is here

> > http://s146485761.onlinehome.fr/wp_dev/plugin_archive.zip

**UPDATE 2**

After a good while I just realized there was nothing wrong with the code, it only needed to be placed 1 level higher in my plugin folder. I created this "bulletproof" example as a dummy plugin I figured out from there the function & add_action snippets needed to be on the root of th eplugin folder.

In case that helps anyone, here's the test code I used :

```
<?php
   /*
   * Plugin Name: Hello World
   */
   add_filter( 'the_content', 'tfr_the_content' );
   function thisisonlyatest() {
      wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-datepicker');
      wp_enqueue_style('jquery-ui-datepicker','http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.1/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.min.css' );
   }
   add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts","thisisonlyatest");
   function tfr_the_content( $content ) {
      return $content . '<p><input type="text" id="datepicker" value=""/></p>';
   }
   ?>
   <script type="text/javascript">
   jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   jQuery('#datepicker').datepicker({
   dateFormat : 'yy-mm-dd'
   });
   });
   </script>
```

Create a folder in your plugin folder. Create a blank php file in there and paste that code. Fire up your test wordpress instance and customize to your needs from there.

Thanks all for your help, hope this will help others too

Greg

Comment: What page are you including this on? are you actually writing `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>` into the page?

Comment: Yes, I started the plugin dev from scratch as an html page. Hence the basic http ref. But I realize this is not the way to do it once IN wordpress, hence my candid question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the code above is what you're actually using, the issue is that $ isn't a jQuery object. You need something like:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

   /** your code

 });
```

And as the person above was getting at, don't hard code jQuery, enqueue it. Also, just FYI, jQuery datepicker is part of core but the styles for it aren't so you'll need to roll a stylesheet and include that.

For example (using the jQuery Themeroller Redmond style):

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_my_scripts');

function load_my_scripts(){
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-datepicker' );    
wp_register_style('date-picker', plugins_url('css/jquery-ui-redmond.css',__FILE__), true);
}
```

Comment: Also, when enqueueing scripts, it's a best practice to dictate whether or not it relies on another library. COnsidering jQuery Ui Datepicker requires jQuery, you should probably do, `wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-datepicker', 'path/to/my/jquery-ui-datepicker.js', array('jquery'))`, where `array('jquery')` is the magic that most people miss.

Comment: Good call, though as far as I know jQuery is always enqueued so you don't really have to list it as a dependency unless you need a specific version.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answers. When I paste just that code into my plugin, it still won't load jquery :( For debugging purpose, would it help if I move it from a local server to a regular one ?

Comment: Post the full plugin code so we can see how you're actually calling it.

Comment: Sure, here you go : http://s146485761.onlinehome.fr/wp_dev/plugin_archive.zip ; the code posted here is in the includes/shortcode file. Thanks for your help !

Comment: You're adding the load_my_scripts function inside of your shortcode function which means that you're trying to add something to wp_enqueue_scripts after it has already run. http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference

Comment: FYI, useful tip here for how to conditionally load scripts based on the content of the page: http://shibashake.com/wordpress-theme/wp_enqueue_script-after-wp_head

Comment: I would agree this is the way Wordpress.org recommends it to be done. But I myself have problems with it. Datepicker is easy to load when calling external script in Wordpress 3.7.1 but I can't get datepicker to load on the front-end at all. I always end up using scripts on Google but I really want to use Wordpress core.

Comment: Thanks Wunderjojo, your points plus a whole lot of research and test got me to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

**For loading bellows script & style add bellows code on theme functions.php file.**

```
function add_e2_date_picker(){
//jQuery UI date picker file
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-datepicker');
//jQuery UI theme css file
wp_enqueue_style('e2b-admin-ui-css','http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css',false,"1.9.0",false);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_e2_date_picker');
```

**Script for back-end use:**

```
function add_e2_date_picker(){
//jQuery UI date picker file
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-datepicker');
//jQuery UI theme css file
wp_enqueue_style('e2b-admin-ui-css','http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css',false,"1.9.0",false);
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'add_e2_date_picker');
```

I have add or hooked on ‘options-general.php’ for display on Settigns->Date Picker. Just put this code also funtions.php file or bellow those code.

```
function register_datepiker_submenu() {
    add_submenu_page( 'options-general.php', 'Date Picker', 'Date Picker', 'manage_options', 'date-picker', 'datepiker_submenu_callback' );
}

function datepiker_submenu_callback() { ?>

    <div class="wrap">

    <input type="text" class="datepicker" name="datepicker" value=""/>

    </div>

    <script>
    jQuery(function() {
        jQuery( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({
            dateFormat : "dd-mm-yy"
        });
    });
    </script> 

<?php }
add_action('admin_menu', 'register_datepiker_submenu');

?>
```

Please see more details on [Add a jQuery Date Picker to WordPress Theme or Plugin](http://www.e2soft.com/blog/add-a-jquery-date-picker-to-wordpress-theme-or-plugin/)